# Multiple Context Menu options - Tampermonkey

Tags: javascript, scripting, tampermonkey, userscripts

I understand that we can create a context menu option/button with Tampermonkey using

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Context Menu
// @namespace       http://tampermonkey.net/
// @description     Test
// @version         0.1
// @author          author
// @include         *
// @exclude         file://*
// @grant           GM_openInTab
// @grant           GM_registerMenuCommand
// ==/UserScript==]
```

However, I wanted to create multiple context menu options using a single Tampermonkey script and create multiple functions to perform the task according to the menu option/button that user has clicked.

Comment: You can use `GM_registerMenuCommand` to open a pop-up and then put all the requirements in that pop-up.

Comment: Thanks @erosman It worked. Now I can create multiple functions with single Tampermonkey script. However, I am not able to assign a shortcut key to a function. For example I want to call a certain function when I press ALT+J. 

Can you please share how it's done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use `GM_registerMenuCommand` to open a pop-up and then put all the requirements in that pop-up.

AFA shortcut keys, here is an example of how to set it up. You can adjust it according to your needs.

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', keydown);

function keydown(e) {
  
  if (e.altKey && e.key === 'j') {      // ALT+j
    
    e.preventDefault();                 // prevent default action of key
    // do something
  }
}
```